gcov does not cover an executed line
There is an executed section in the code that gcov ignores.
intro:
I am working on a task that we got in class to implement netcat-like program called 'mync' in C using sockets and system calls to in order to play tic-tac-toe user vs CPU.
i compile the program with '-fprofile-arcs' '-ftest-coverage'.
i communicate with the program using the command line and, the program get all sorts of flags and parameters after them so a command can look something like this :
./mync -e "./ttt 123456789" -i TCPS9988
The command above will execute the tic-tac-toe program in a child process and gives it the moves the CPU will want to do each turn, and the program will get the moves of the user from the TCP server that listens to the user.
If i use the command "./mync -e "./ttt 123456789" -i TCPS9988 "
gcove will mark the lines inside 'if (evalue != NULL)' as executed (which is good):
    1:  757:        RUN(evalue);  
    -:  758:    } else            //(evalue == NULL)
    -:  759:    {
#####:  760:        printf("No -e command provided\n");

The problem starts here:
If i don't write '-e' the program should start a chat between TCP server and client which works fine,
and "No -e command provided" will be printed to the terminal.
enter image description here
but the gcov STILL marks this line as unexecuted:
    1:  757:        RUN(evalue); 
    -:  758:    } else            //(evalue == NULL)
    -:  759:    {
#####:  760:        printf("No -e command provided\n");

i dont understand what can possibly cause this problem ?
i compile the program with '-fprofile-arcs' '-ftest-coverage'.
if (evalue != NULL) {
    if (descriptors[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {
        ---- not relevant ----
    }
    if (descriptors[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {
        ---- not relevant ----
    }
    RUN(evalue);  // this gets the whole command string and runs it
} 
else            //(evalue == NULL)
{
    printf("**No -e command provided**\n");
    -----
}

if more information is needed i will gladly add it, just let me know.
